# SqlException in app using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, ado.net

Hey I just started learning to make application in C# using back-end as sql.
I put some breakpoints to see that the control never comes back after executing the `cntCeilInn.Open();`
soon, the output window shows '`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`' occurred in `System.Data.dll`

Google tells me its not timing out or something that I couldn't understand. Some help please.

```
string strServerName="EXPRESSION";

using (SqlConnection cntCeilInn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + strServerName + ";" + "Integrated Security=YES"))
{
    SqlCommand cmdCeilInn= new SqlCommand("If exists ("+ "Select name "+ "from sys.database "+ "Where name=N'CeilInn1')"+ "DROP database CeilInn1;"+ "go"+ "create database CeilInn1;", cntCeilInn);
    cntCeilInn.Open();
    cmdCeilInn.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: You can try catch the Exception and debug with its Exception message.

Comment: Check the exception message and its details, post it with your question

Comment: Have you included System.Data.SqlClient Namespace?

Comment: Why do you have a string literal split up into little parts? Perhaps the problem is that there's no space between `)` and `DROP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your sql query .

1. It's `sys.databases` not `sys.database`
2. No space between `Go` and `Create` syntax
3. You need to place the sql statements in seperate line
4. Not to mention do check your `connection string` once as others have stated

Try this out

```
SqlCommand cmdCeilInn = new SqlCommand("If exists (" + "Select name " + "from sys.databases " + "Where name=N'Sample') DROP database Sample;" 
                      +Environment .NewLine+ "go " + Environment .NewLine 
                     +" create database Sample;", cntCeilInn);
```

Comment: @camelbrush : Please mark it as an answer if any of the suggestion helped you

Answer (score 1):

As **connectionString** parameter,you should use:

```
Data Source=yourServerName;Initial Catalog=yourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True
```

make sure to modify `youServerName` and `yourDatabaseName` by appropriate data.

Note that you forgot to set the database name in your connectionString(**Initial Catalog**), and the value for Integrated Security is **True**.